# Getting NULL values while using OPENXML to read from XML file

Tags: sql, xml, import, openxml

Why I get NULL values while trying to read the XML document (file example below) into SQL server? I think its due to reading the file. First part of SQL seems to be ok - I see the xml file in SQLSERVER grid. But dont know, how to read the data. Idea is - that I want to import the XML file into SQL SERVER, do some data cleansing with simple SQL queries, then import that into other system.

this XML uses DTD.

Thanks for help.

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)    

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML WHERE ID = '1' -- The row to process    

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML


SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/BMECAT/HEADER/CATALOG/',1)
WITH 
(
language nvarchar(max)
)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO


<!-- Generated by crossbase mediasolution GmbH (http://www.crossbase.de) -->
<BMECAT xmlns="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/1.2/bmecat_new_catalog" version="1.2">
<HEADER>
<CATALOG>
  <LANGUAGE>DE</LANGUAGE>
  <CATALOG_ID>ML103</CATALOG_ID>
  <CATALOG_VERSION>1</CATALOG_VERSION>
  <DATETIME type="generation_date">
    <DATE>2015-10-12</DATE>
    <TIME>07:10:42</TIME>
    <TIMEZONE>+02:00</TIMEZONE>
  </DATETIME>
</CATALOG>
<BUYER>
  <ADDRESS type="buyer" />
</BUYER>
<SUPPLIER>
  <SUPPLIER_NAME>GmbH</SUPPLIER_NAME>
  <ADDRESS type="supplier">
    <NAME>GmbH</NAME>
    <NAME2>fabrik</NAME2>
    <STREET>e 1</STREET>
    <ZIP>6973</ZIP>
    <CITY>st</CITY>
    <COUNTRY>eich</COUNTRY>
    <PHONE>05-0</PHONE>
    <FAX>705-44</FAX>
    <EMAIL>info@com</EMAIL>
    <URL>www.com</URL>
  </ADDRESS>
</SUPPLIER>
```

Comment: Hi, my first answer was to short thoughted... Please have a look at the edited answer. As stated in my first attempt the problem you have is due to the namespace declaration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for the original file. I loaded it down and could read this without problems:. Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @yourXML AS XML=
(
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
);

--simple approach
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/1.2/bmecat_new_catalog')
SELECT @YourXML.value('(/BMECAT/HEADER/CATALOG/LANGUAGE)[1]','varchar(2)');

--with OPENXML
DECLARE @hDoc INT;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc output, @YourXML,'<root xmlns:dflt="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/1.2/bmecat_new_catalog" />';

SELECT LANGUAGE
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc,'/dflt:BMECAT/dflt:HEADER/dflt:CATALOG') 
WITH(LANGUAGE VARCHAR(MAX) 'dflt:LANGUAGE'); 

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Following you find a bunch of XML examples - with or without namespaces - to compare and find the best approach you need. Just paste this into an empty query window and execute:

```
DECLARE @xmlNaked XML='<root><element test="SomeValue"/></root>';
DECLARE @xmlNamespace XML='<root xmlns="http://testNS" xmlns:ns2="http://testNS/ns2"><element test="SomeValue"/><ns2:namespaced test2="another value"/></root>';

--Normale approach
SELECT @xmlNaked.value('(/root/element/@test)[1]','varchar(max)') AS TheElement;

--No return value due to namespace
SELECT @xmlNamespace.value('(/root/element/@test)[1]','varchar(max)') AS TheElementMissing
      ,@xmlNamespace.value('(/root/namespaced/@test2)[1]','varchar(max)') AS NamespacedMissing; 

--Declaring default namespace before (xmlns is the default, ns2 additional)
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://testNS')
SELECT @xmlNamespace.value('(/root/element/@test)[1]','varchar(max)') AS TheElement
      ,@xmlNamespace.value('(/root/namespaced/@test2)[1]','varchar(max)') AS NamespacedMissing; 

--Declaring default namespace and additional namespace
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://testNS/ns2' AS ns2, DEFAULT 'http://testNS')
SELECT @xmlNamespace.value('(/root/element/@test)[1]','varchar(max)') AS TheElement
      ,@xmlNamespace.value('(/root/ns2:namespaced/@test2)[1]','varchar(max)') AS NamespacedMissing; 

--now with OPENXML, namespaces must be introduced in sp_xml_preparedocument
DECLARE @i INT, @ns VARCHAR(100);
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i output, @xmlNaked;
SELECT test AS TheElement FROM OPENXML(@i,'/root/element',2) WITH(test VARCHAR(MAX) '@test') 

--not return value due to namespace
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i output, @xmlNamespace;
SELECT test AS TheElementMissing FROM OPENXML(@i,'/root/element',2) WITH(test VARCHAR(MAX) '@test') 

--There's AFAIK no "direct" declaration of the default namespace possible. Look at the declaration of "dflt" namespace
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i output, @xmlNamespace,'<root xmlns:dflt="http://testNS" />';
SELECT test AS TheElement FROM OPENXML(@i,'/dflt:root/dflt:element') WITH(test VARCHAR(MAX)) 

--Now the full thing
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i output, @xmlNamespace,'<root xmlns:dflt="http://testNS" xmlns:ns2="http://testNS/ns2"/>';
SELECT test AS TheElement,test2 AS Namespace 
FROM OPENXML(@i,'/dflt:root',2) 
     WITH   (test VARCHAR(MAX) 'dflt:element/@test'
            ,test2 VARCHAR(MAX) 'ns2:namespaced/@test2'  )
```

Comment: No need for me to use OPENXML. I tried that OPENXML because I found such an example of it. But no need for that, any workable solution is great

Comment: @GediminasŠatkauskas, in this case, where the XML is so big, it should be a good idea to use OPENXML, if you want to retrieve different values from different sections. If you just read the language, the simple approach should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your example works. Both methods. But now I try to read directly from file. Nothing happens - the NULL is returned as previously. What I do incorrectly?:

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

DECLARE @yourXML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)    

SELECT @yourXML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML WHERE ID = '1' -- The row to process    

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @yourXML


--with OPENXML
 DECLARE @i INT;
 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i output, @YourXML,'<root xmlns:dflt="http://www.bmecat.org/bmecat/1.2/bmecat_new_catalog" />';
SELECT LANGUAGE 
FROM OPENXML(@i,'/dflt:BMECAT/dflt:HEADER/dflt:CATALOG') WITH(LANGUAGE VARCHAR(MAX) 'dflt:LANGUAGE'); 

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Comment: Hi, found your answer per incidence. This should be a comment below my answer. Otherwise there's no notification... I'll continue below my answer...

Comment: Hi, I'll write my comment here, otherwise you would not get the notification :-) I just added a new EDIT to my answer to give a working example with your acutal data. Please vote up and mark as accepted if this solves your problem, thx!

Comment: Hi, once again... There was a problem with the code formatting. I just found, that my answer was not readable properly. So - if you already had a look on this - it is corrected now...

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. Can you help with DTD parse? I think its not parsed correctly. See the code. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you write `SELECT @yourXML` right before the `EXEC sp_xml_prepare...` I'd like to know whether the reading was working or not... Which content is within this variable after reading? Please poste...

Comment: That part gives XML file in one row in Results window:  `    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn,2) AS BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

  `

Comment: If the XML is read correctly it must work... Please check, whether the declared Variable `@YourXML` is filled correctly and please poste - if this is possible  - the full content of you variable. XML is **very** sensible, if the XPath-expression is not correct.

Comment: The XML file here is big - 24 mb. Cant post it. The result windows is clickable - I can click on that xml, and open it in SQL window, and the end of file seems to be ok -   </T_NEW_CATALOG>
</BMECAT>. Whole window is in normal readable format.

Comment: I found another SQL sentence, the same idea to read the XML, but I cant find out how to read any row result (bolded the sql):  ` DECLARE @Data XML;
CREATE TABLE #Xml ( Data XML );
INSERT  INTO #Xml
        ( Data        
        )
        SELECT  CONVERT(XML,BulkColumn,2)
        FROM    OPENROWSET(BULK N'H:\file.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) O;
SELECT @Data = Data FROM #Xml ;
DROP TABLE #Xml;

** SELECT  Element.value('(/BMECAT/HEADER/CATALOG/LANGUAGE)[1]','varchar(2)')
FROM    @Data.nodes('/BMECAT/HEADER/CATALOG') Datalist ( Element ); ** `

Comment: But with `SELECT CONVERT(...) FROM OPENROWSET(...)` you do not check, if this is correctly transfered into the variable @YourXML. Please check, whether the content is correctly loaded into this variable. And please make sure, that the path to your node is exactly as you posted. For example the end-tag `</T_NEW_CATALOG>` was not part of your posted code... Such differences can be the reason for NULL results...

Comment: I checked the @YourXML - it seems to be ok ( I can see the human readable xml file in that variable). I uploaded the xml here: wetransfer link - http://we.tl/vDDgJQneD3

Comment: Hi, look at my edited answer. I could load this file from the harddisc and read the language without problems. Good luck!

Comment: @Shnugo, thank you for a working solution! I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem. I will mark it complete. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to read this! Thank you for accepting my answer. I just pushed you over the magic 15 reputation points. Now you are able to vote on answers. If you don't mind it would be very kind to vote my answer up too. Thx!